# Socket communication with different types of messages

Tags: c#, sockets, design-patterns, architecture, network-programming

I need to develop a web application that communicates to a socket in two different way carrying different types of messages.

1. Web application sends messages to socket and wait for a response for it. (two way communication)
2. Socket pushes messages to web application without a request. (one way communication)
   The size of messages may vary by types, so the socket sends a message containing a pre-considerd  number of characters telling the length of the following message.

Can you please suggest a design or technology to accomplish this communication in an efficient way in a multi-threaded environment?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

[SignalR - Your problem: Solved.](http://signalr.net/)

Seriously, this is exactly what SignalR is designed for.

Comment: But my question is about the communication between socket server and iis server not about the communication between iis server and clients. I'm already using SignalR for that part.